# What are good examples of use of Windows Enclaves?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-management

I was just skimming through Windows Memory Management and found a set of interesting new functions called [Enclave Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366781.aspx#enclave_functions). From the function specification it seems this functionality is new and available only from Windows 10. From the context of the specification i have a feeling it is a WinAPI analogy to .Net AppDomain.

Does anybody know more details about these functions? What are the real-life situations when I should consider to use them?

Comment: They are interfaces to Intel's SGX technology https://software.intel.com/en-us/sgx

Comment: Note that historically, system administrators have been reluctant to enable this sort of technology on their hardware, because of the security implications.  So don't get too attached to it. :-)

Comment: For the record, I have no idea what you're trying to say, @HarryJohnston. Which security implications are you implying? :)

Comment: @amn, see, e.g., https://www.virusbulletin.com/virusbulletin/2014/01/sgx-good-bad-and-downright-ugly

Comment: Also note that to use enclaves on Windows, your process needs to be signed by Microsoft-issued certificate, and as far as I know, they don't issue them to anyone.